# ElasticSearch NEST GET response not deserialized

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, get, deserialization, nest

We connect to an ElasticSearch from a third party to get some data with the NEST nuget package. However if we use the GET<> call the response is not deserialized in a strong typed POCO. The HTTP call is successful and in the body there is a json object with data.

```
var result = _elasticSearchClient.Get<Contractor>(188153, request => request
.Index("{index_name}")
.Type("{type_name}"));

--POCO. Naming of the property as in the json message
public class Contractor
{
public int contractor_id { get; set; }
public string type { get; set; }
public string type_description { get; set; }
public string contractor_code { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
...
}
```

A call with HttpClient and JsonCovert to Deserialize the object works

```
var response = Task.Run(() => _httpClient.GetAsync(url)).Result;
var responseMessage = Task.Run(() => response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;
var contractor = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contractor>(responseMessage);
```

Configuration of the ElasticSearchClient

```
var url = new Uri($"{BaseUrl}");

var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(url);
connectionSettings.ClientCertificate(GetCertificateFromStore());
connectionSettings.BasicAuthentication(Username, Password);
connectionSettings.ThrowExceptions();
connectionSettings.PrettyJson();
connectionSettings.DisableDirectStreaming();
connectionSettings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);

var elasticSearchClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

DebugInformation:
Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on GET: /{index_name}/{type_name}/188153?pretty=true

Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: https://{baseUrl}/ Took: 00:00:01.0835021
Request: Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.

Response:

```
{
  "_index" : "{index_name}",
  "_type" : "{type_name}",
  "_id" : "188153",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "contractor" : {
      "contractor_id" : 188153,
      "type" : "OVE",
      "type_description" : "Overig",
      "contractor_code" : "RES0000826",
      "name" : "OrganizationName", 
   }
}
```

NEST NuGet package 5.6.0

Elasticsearch version 6.0.0

What am I missing?

Comment: what version of NEST are you using? What version of Elasticsearch are you running against? What does `.DebugInformation` on `result` say?

Comment: I edited the question with the additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not deserialized by NEST because the `_source` document in Elasticsearch is an object with one property, `"contractor"`, whose value is an object containing properties.

In order to deserialize correctly, the `_source` document in Elasticsearch would need to be

```
  "_source" : {
      "contractor_id" : 188153,
      "type" : "OVE",
      "type_description" : "Overig",
      "contractor_code" : "RES0000826",
      "name" : "OrganizationName"
   }
```

**or alternatively**, the POCO should be something like

```
public class ContractorWrapper //choose any type name you like :)
{
    public Contractor contractor { get;set; }
}
```

to match the JSON structure.

Comment: Is this a best practice to put a object in Source or should be the root of Contractor object in _source?

Comment: @Devliegendebeer `_source` contains the JSON document as it was sent to Elasticsearch when it was indexed. I think in your case here, the `_source` JSON should be how I've shown in the first code sample. If you can, I'd be inclined to change the indexing code to serialize like this.